# Is a header file a translation unit?

Tags: c++, c, file, header-files, translation-unit

Is a header file a translation unit? If I add the static keyword to a variable in a header file, could I call that variable in my .c or .cpp file? Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close as too broad since you have asked 2 questions. For your titular one, this would be a duplicate of [What is a “translation unit” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

No, headers are not separate translation units.

Each .c/.cpp file is a separate translation unit, and since preprocessor textually replaces `#include`s with the contents of the headers, code from all headers included (directly or indirectly) by a .c/.cpp file is a part of that file's translation unit.

In other words, a translation unit is a .c or .cpp file after preprocessing.

Answer (score 3):

No, a translation unit is the full output of the preprocessor.  A header file will be included and its content may become a part of the translation unit.